# How to locate and click Radio Button through the Label using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I want to uncheck the radio button on a webpage which is checked by default but i am getting error

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not
>   interactable"

Can someone please help me to correct my code which i am trying?

```
WebElement travellerbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Traveller']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']"));
travellerbutton.click();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="tgselect" id="traveller" checked="">
    <label for="traveller">Traveller</label>
    <div class="check"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: XML code is:<div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="tgselect" id="traveller" checked=""><label for="traveller">Traveller</label><div class="check"></div></div>
<input type="radio" name="tgselect" id="traveller" checked="">
<label for="traveller">Traveller</label>

Comment: Radio buttons are not check boxes: clicking on them will not "uncheck" them.

Comment: More concretely, why don't you just get the element by its id, "traveller" ?

Comment: Thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas ! i misunderstood the radio button with checkbox and my code was not working with using Id previously but now i tried again and it is working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element associated with the `<label>` with text as **Traveller** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='Traveller']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='Traveller']")).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there are several radio buttons and you need to select another one. But in case, you can uncheck radio button using JavaScript, try code below:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].checked=false;", driver.findElement(By.id("traveller")));
```